# Use Scala Manifest to dynamically instantiate Objects

Tags: scala, manifest

I am wondering if it is possible to instantiate an `object` (companion object) dynamically using `Manifest`. I want to parse json in MongoRecord but to do so, I have to understand which is the type that is passed.

```
def getCompanion[T](implicit mf : Manifest[T])={
    if (mf <:< classOf[MongoRecord[C]]){
       Class[C].asInstanceOf[MongoRecord].setFieldsFromJSON(request.body.toString)
    }

}
```

but I am receiving an error during compilation:

> error: object Class is not a value
>   Class[C].asInstanceOf[MongoRecord].setFieldsFromJSON(request.body.toString)

it is a difficult topic to me. Perhaps it is not feasible but I would like to know if it is possible?
Thanks

Comment: You cannot instantiate (companion) objects at all. Please clarify.

Comment: I would like to call a method that is callable in this way MongoRecordCompanionObject.setFieldsFromJSON(jsonString).   For sure I could do this using pattern matching on manifest erasure but I would like to know if I can call a companion dinamically knowing its name at runtime (without reflection). Is it possible?

Comment: And how would you invoke `getCompanion`? Probably not as `getCompanion[MongoRecordCompanionObject]` - maybe `getCompanion` should take as an argument some instance of which you'd like to get the companion object?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172775/get-companion-object-of-class-by-given-generic-type-scala and at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020746/get-companion-object-instance-with-new-scala-reflection-api