# Trying to use Jackson to read value to a parameterized type with scala

Tags: json, scala, generics, jackson

I'm trying to write a method that will allow Jackson ObjectMapper readValue on a json string to a parameterized object type.  Something like this

```
case class MyObj(field1: String, field2: String)

val objectMapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule)

def fromJson[T](jsonString: String, objTyp: T): T = {

    objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, classOf[T])

}

val x = fromJson("""{"field1": "something", "field2": "something"}""", MyObj)
```

This of course returns an error of

```
class type required but T found
```

i've looked at this issue [Scala classOf for type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200253/scala-classof-for-type-parameter)
but it doesn't seem to help.  It seems like this is possible to do somehow.  Looking for any help

Comment: Jackson Scala module already provides such helper methods, it's not clear why you need to reimplement them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give it the actual runtime class to parse into, not just a type parameter.

One way to do it is passing the class directly:

```
def fromJson[T](json: String, clazz: Class[T]) = objectMapper.readValue[T](json, clazz)

val x = fromJson("""...""", classOf[MyObj])
```

Alternatively, you can use `ClassTag`, which looks a bit messier in implementation, but kinda prettier at call site:

```
def fromJson[T : ClassTag](json: String): T = objectMapper.readValue[T](
  json, 
  implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
)

val x = fromJson[MyObj]("""{"field1": "something", "field2": "something"}""")
```

Comment: `implicitly[ClassTag[T]]` can be replaced with `classTag[T]` (lower-case)

Answer (score 1):

> i've looked at this issue [Scala classOf for type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200253/scala-classof-for-type-parameter) but it doesn't seem to help.

In the very first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6200301/5249621) there it's written `classTag[T].runtimeClass` as a replacement of `classOf[T]`. This should help.

Regarding the signature

```
def fromJson[T](jsonString: String, objTyp: T): T
```

You should notice that `MyObj` has type `MyObj.type` (companion-object type), not `MyObj` (case-class type).

[Class companion object vs. case class itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286750/class-companion-object-vs-case-class-itself/)

So if you call `fromJson("""...""", MyObj)` then the types in these two places

```
def fromJson[...](jsonString: String, objTyp: ???): ???
                                              ^^^   ^^^  <--- HERE
```

can't be the same.

If it's enough for you to call

```
fromJson("""...""", classOf[MyObj])
```

or

```
fromJson[MyObj]("""...""")
```

(normally it should be enough) then please see @Dima's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75462471/5249621), you should prefer those options, they're easier.

Just in case, if you really want to call like `fromJson("""...""", MyObj)` then for example you can use the type class `ToCompanion` (this is more complicated) from

[Invoke construcotr based on passed parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75349051/invoke-construcotr-based-on-passed-parameter)

[Get companion object of class by given generic type Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172775/get-companion-object-of-class-by-given-generic-type-scala) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74726266/5249621))

```
// ToCompanion should be defined in a different subproject

def fromJson[C, T](jsonString: String, objTyp: C)(implicit
  toCompanion: ToCompanion.Aux[C, T],
  classTag: ClassTag[T]
): T =
  objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, classTag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])

val x = fromJson("""{"field1": "something", "field2": "something"}""", MyObj)
// MyObj(something,something)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I checked @Dima's as that is what I actually implemented but your answer was really helpful in understanding the issue.